# Comportamiento extraño renderizando un gráfico desde apexcharts

Tags: laravel, apex-chart

estoy trabajando con la librería ApexCharts y estoy notando el siguiente comportamiento: tengo que mostrar un gráfico en un componente livewire, que se actualiza en función de un evento disparado desde un button. Lo extraño es que el gráfico se muestra pero al terminar de renderizarse, desaparece, volviendo a aparecer si cambio el tamaño de la pantalla o ingreso a inspección de código, lo extraño es que al cerrar el inspector, aparece nuevamente el gráfico.

Este es código de mi componente livewire y lo que necesito es que el gráfico se genera cuando se dispara el evento grafDelitos.

Población Penitenciaria año {{ $aniCenso }}

```
    <div class="bg-white rounded-md border p-3 w-auto mt-2 shadow-sm shadow-green-600">
        <h4>Total Personas Privadas de Libertad</h4>
        <div class="text-2xl font-bold text-center">{{ number_format($totPersonasPL,0) }}</div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid grid-cols-3 mt-2 gap-2 text-center">
        <div class="bg-white rounded-md border w-auto py-1 shadow-sm shadow-blue-500">
            <h4 class="text-sm">Condenados</h4>
            <div class="text-2xl font-bold text-center">{{ number_format($totCondenados,0) }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-white rounded-md border w-auto py-1 shadow-sm shadow-green-600">
            <h4 class="text-sm">Procesados</h4>
            <div class="text-2xl font-bold text-center">{{ number_format($totProcesados,0) }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-white rounded-md border w-auto py-1 shadow-sm shadow-blue-500">
            <h4 class="text-sm">Otros</h4>
            <div class="text-2xl font-bold text-center">{{ number_format($totInimpOtros,0) }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid grid-cols-2 mt-2 gap-2 text-center">
        <div class="bg-white rounded-md border w-auto py-1 shadow-sm shadow-green-600">
            <h4 class="text-sm">Argentinos</h4>
            <div class="text-2xl font-bold text-center">{{ $totArgentinos }}%</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-white rounded-md border w-auto py-1 shadow-sm shadow-blue-500">
            <h4 class="text-sm">Varones</h4>
            <div class="text-2xl font-bold text-center">{{ $totVarones }}%</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid grid-cols-2 mt-2 gap-2 text-center">
        <div class="bg-white rounded-md border w-auto py-1 shadow-sm shadow-blue-500">
            <h4 class="text-sm">Menores de 35 años</h4>
            <div class="text-2xl font-bold text-center">{{ $totMenores35 }}%</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-white rounded-md border w-auto py-1 shadow-sm shadow-green-600">
            <h4 class="text-sm">Estudios Primarios</h4>
            <div class="text-2xl font-bold text-center">{{ $totEstPrimarios }}%</div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="graf1" style="width: 290px; height: 290px; z-index: 999">
    </div>


    <script>
        Livewire.on('IngresarAnio', () => {
            Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Atención!!',
            html: '<p>Debe indica el Año...</p>',
            })
        });
    </script>


<script>

    Livewire.on('grafDelitos', (varDatos) => {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                width: 300,
                type: 'pie',
            },
            series: [44,55,13,33],
            labels: ['Apple', 'Mango', 'Orange', 'Watermelon']
        }

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#graf1"), options);

        chart.render();
    })

</script>


</div>
```

Este evento se genera desde otro componente livewire mediante la siguiente instrucción:

```
$this->varJson4 = json_encode($frecVarDelitos);
$this->emit('grafDelitos', $this->varJson4);
```

Bueno, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias y saludos.